# Entity Framework Multiple Independent Updates in one round trip

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to save multiple entities without a 'transaction' in a single round trip?  What I mean is that if I have 100 entities to save and 5 fail due to say, a unique constraint violation, then the other 95 should be updated in the database.  Example code:

```
var entities = GetEntitiesToUpdate(); // list of 100 entities to update

// working but slow example
using var db = new Ctx();
entities.ForEach(e => {
  db.Add(e);
  try { db.SaveChanges(); } // results in 100 roundtrips
  catch (e) { LogException(e); } // errors are logged but execution continues
});

// non working but fast code
using var db = new Ctx();
db.AddRange(entities);
db.SaveChanges(); // Exception, causes all 100 updates to be aborted
```

Comment: Think how you would do that in pure SQL, could you do it without transactions?

Comment: @DavidG I'm using SQL Server and that has TRY CATCH. So `BEGIN CATCH END CATCH;` would ignore the errors and continue.  I doubt there is a ansi SQL compliant way.